# Looking for a TCPInboundGateway with auto-reply or no-ack

Tags: spring-integration

I am a client of a service which streams XML documents over a socket to me firehose-style.  Once the connection is established, no messages are expected from me, and my code gets to desperately try to keep up with incoming data.

For this I am using a `tcp-inbound-gateway` in client mode:

```xml
<ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="inGateway"
    request-channel="socketInChannel"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    reply-timeout="10000"
    retry-interval="5000"
    auto-startup="false"
    client-mode="true"/>
```

My connection factory includes a custom deserializer which detects start and end tags on the streamed XML to chop the stream into documents.  Each doc is sent downstream to the `socketInChannel` for processing by other components.

```xml
<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
    type="client"
    host="${socket.url}"
    port="${socket.port}"
    single-use="false"
    so-keep-alive="true"
    interceptor-factory-chain="authInterceptorFactory"
    deserializer="xmlDeserializer"
    serializer="xmlDeserializer"/>
```

All of this works...but I've found that I am not pulling data out of my socket anywhere near quickly enough.  I eventually realized that I was processing 1 message every 10s like clockwork.  So I immediately blame the `reply-timeout` on the `tcp-inbound-gateway`.  Drop that down to 100 and voila, I'm able to keep up.

Now, my best guess as to why this worked is that the `tcp-inbound-gateway` is expecting a reply from my downstream component but none is forthcoming.  When I minimize the `reply-timeout` it gives up waiting for a reply quickly and moves on to the next message from the socket.

This does not seem like an ideal solution.  Since the firehose expects no responses from me, my gateway forwards each message into a QueueChannel for decoupled consumer code to pull from.

Is there a way to configure the `tcp-inbound-gateway` to not expect a reply?  If not, what's the cleanest way to push the incoming message in a `QueueChannel` and then auto-acknowledge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `<inbound-channel-adapter/>` instead of a  `<gateway/>`.

Channel adapters are specifically intended for one-way integration scenarios, whereas gateways are normally for request/reply.